# How can I scroll right when inserting a character in draft js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, draftjs

With draft-js and a styled component, I made an inline input intended for a calculator. When I type into it with a keyboard, it works as expected:

[image]

When I press the plus button, a "+" is added to the text, but the view doesn't scroll:

[image]

Here's the behavior and the code in a codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-brattain-mvkj3?from-embed=&file=/src/index.js

How can I get the view to scroll when text is added programmatically like that?

Comment: It will be much easier if you can create a reproducible snippet using codesandbox or something

Comment: @MoshFeu good idea—I've now included a codesandbox link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At long last, I figured out a solution. I added this to the calculator input component:

```
const shell = React.useRef(null);
const [scrollToggle, setScrollToggle] = React.useState(
  { value: false }
);

React.useEffect(() => {
  const scrollMax = shell.current.scrollWidth - shell.current.clientWidth;
  shell.current.scrollLeft += scrollMax;
}, [scrollToggle]);

const scrollToEnd = () => {
  setScrollToggle({ value: !scrollToggle.value });
};
```

Then at the end of the insertChars function I added `scrollToEnd();`.

And I set `ref={shell}` on `<InputShell>`